# Mouse scrolling in CDE file manager

Tags: solaris, mouse, scrolling

I cannot scroll using the mouse wheel inside CDE file manager (dtfile). Scrolling inside terminal or text editor or anything else works fine. How can I configure it to allow for mouse wheel scrolling?

Solaris 10 on SPARC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember if I ever found a solution that worked with dtfile.  The other CDE applications simply needed additions to their `app-defaults` files, which users could also provide via their `$HOME/.Xdefaults` as shown in an ancient blog entry at https://blogs.oracle.com/alanc/entry/wheel_mouse_support_in_solaris.